# Basic trigonometry with popsicle sticks

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to make a model out of popsicle sticks of half a cycle of a sine wave.  It is easy to do it in a crude way.  Just stack up the sticks, draw half a cycle of a sine wave on the sticks, then cut the sticks to fit.

I am trying to calculate the lengths of the sticks, but something goes wrong.  I think it should be $\cos(sin^{-1}( x/n ) )$ where n is the number of sticks in the stack and x is 0 through n-1. But the answers are wrong.  What is the correct method?

Comment: Are you making them in a "integral boxes" manner or are you connecting them on the contour of $\sin x$?

Comment: I'm confused about how exactly you're trying to put the sticks together. My first thought was that you want "vertical" trapezoids, with a horizontal bottom edge that aligns with the $x$-axis, and a slanting upper edge that approximates the curve of the sine wave. But, then, each stick itself doesn't have **a** length; it has **two** lengths: the trapezoid's vertical "bases". (Two adjacent sticks share a common base-length.) Is this what you want? Or do you want "horizontal" trapezoids that slope on the left- and right-hand sides? (There, too, you need two lengths per stick.)

Comment: this one i learned from steinhaus' mathematical snapshots. you wrap a paper around a cylindrical object, say, a candle. now cut it at an angle and unwrap the paper. you will have the graph of $\sin.$

Answer (score 1):

By half cycle, I assume $[0, \pi]$.  The height of the $n$th popsicle stick is $\sin(n*\pi/(total+1))$

Comment: If the sticks are vertically that is.

Answer (score 0):

If the full sine-wave has amplitude A (popsicle maximum height) and wave-length $\lambda$, popsicle

thickness $ \Delta x $ its standard equation is:

$$  n \Delta x = \lambda  $$

$$ y = A  \sin [ 2 \pi (n \Delta x) / \lambda ] $$

You can choose half wave with half this $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The popsicle sticks are horizontal.  (The clue is that it says I'm using a stack of sticks.  You can't stack vertical sticks.)

It is true that each stick has two different lengths if you want to do it exactly.  One length for the upper surface and another for the lower.  But I don't care about that.   Cutting sticks at an angle other than 90 degrees is too hard.  Either length is good enough.  It gets a "digitized" look that I like.  Or I can sand off the extra if I like.